# Degree value to two float variables

Tags: lua, angle

I need help creating a function to convert an angle to two float variables.

Here are some examples of the outputs:

- 0 degrees = {1, 0}
- ~31.0760 degrees = {~0.92823970, ~0.37198266}
- 45 degrees= {~0.70707070, ~0.70707070}
- 90 degrees = {0, 1}
- 135 degrees = {~-0.707070707, ~0.707070707}
- 180 degrees = {-1, 0}
- 225 degrees = {~-0.707070707, ~-0.707070707}
- ~240.2409 degrees = {~-0.35347452, ~-0.93544417}
- 270 degrees = {0, -1}
- 315 degrees = {~0.70707070, ~-0.70707070}

Comment: Could I get some more specifics (for example what language you need it in). Id be happy to show you how to do it.

Comment: From the tag, I'm guessing the language is lua, but it would definitely be better to mention it in the question.

Comment: It is lua, sorry for not mentioning it in the question.

Comment: math.rad, math.acos, math.asin will be helpful :).

Comment: @Micho No, the tag is enough. In general, it's not necessary to Mention it in the question .

Comment: Are you sure about the values for 31.0760 and 240.2409 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if you are hung up on the syntax or the algorithmic part of this problem. I figure the syntax is simpler to look up so I will offer the simple calculation.

Your tuple will be calculated using the lua math functions: math.rad, math.cos, math.sin

```
{math.cos(math.rad(degrees)), math.sin(math.rad(degrees))}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This does not give you the values the OP gave for 31.0760 degrees. But then I don't know what does...